# Get more columns from inner select using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to retrieve more columns from inner selected table and store it to another table. Here is the following example of the same.

**Example**:

My First Try:

```
create table "A_B_1" as select "SlNo","Rlno", 0 as got,"Name" as Nm,"Address" as Addr,
from    (
         select  "Rlno","SlNo", count(*) over (partition by "Rlno") cnt
         from    (
                  select  distinct "SlNo","Rlno"
                  from alldata
                  ) b
         ) a
where   cnt > 1
```

**Error**: column "Name" does not exists.

**Note** All fields all available in `alldata` table. But I am not getting why is such error occurred here.

My Second Try:

```
create table "A_B_1" as select "SlNo","Rlno", 0 as got,ad."Name" as Nm,ad."Address" as Addr,
from    (
         select  "Rlno","SlNo", count(*) over (partition by "Rlno") cnt
         from    (
                  select  distinct "SlNo","Rlno"
                  from alldata as ad
                  ) b
         ) a
where   cnt > 1
```

**Error**: missing FROM-clause entry for table "m"

Comment: Can you run the internal SQL statement? Post a sample output..

Comment: @Adrian, You mean `select distinct "SlNo","RlNo" from alldata`?

Comment: Yes, what the "b" entity looks like; same for "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    "SlNo",
    "Rlno",
    0 as got,
    Nm,
    Addr
from  (
    select "Rlno", "SlNo", Nm, Addr, count(*) over (partition by "Rlno") cnt
    from (
        select distinct on ("SlNo", "Rlno")
            "S1No", "R1no", "Name" as Nm, "Address" as Addr
        from alldata
    ) b
) a
where cnt > 1
```